# Finding the rows of data in a database

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on my python script as I want to count for every 69 row in a database to get a list of values. I need some help with my code because some of them are wrong.

When I try this:

```
test = con.cursor()
test.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM programs")
x = test.fetchone()[0]
running_total = 1 #Again, you want to start counting at 1 for some reason
while running_total < x:
    running_total += 69
    print running_total
```

I will get the result like this:

```
70
139
208
277
346
415
484
553
622
691
760
829
898
967
1036
1105
```

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
1
70
139
208
277
346
415
484
553
622
691
760
829
898
967
1036
```

I want to output the values that start with `1`, then `70`, `139`, `208`...etc until I get the last 69 values in a database. Example: I have the `1104` rows in my database and the last 69 rows I want to get is `1036` and ignore the last row `1104`.

Another example: If I add another 69 rows of data in a database that I have the rows `1104` to get full rows in total `1173`, the last 69 rows I want to get is `1104` and ignore the last row `1173`. It will be depends on how many rows of data that I add in a database.

Can you please help me how I can output the values that start with `1`, then add up 69 each time to make `70`, `139`, `208`...etc until I get the last 69 rows and then to ignore the last row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make use of the range/xrange function:

`range` (Python3) and `xrange` (Python2) have the following form: `range(start, end, increment)` where `start` is inclusive and `end` is non-inclusive.

```
test = con.cursor()
test.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM programs")
x = test.fetchone()[0]
for running_total in xrange(1, x + 1, 69):
    print(running_total)
```

This should get you the desired output without resorting to C-style incrementing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help matt, problem are now solved!